# ZF2 User group specific layouts

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-acl, zend-layout

I have a project with 3 different Layouts. 1 Layout for the Login page, 1 Layout for the administrators and editors and a 3rd Layout for general users where also the administrators have access to (its a layout for 3 different pages where you can fill out surveys which is possible for the 3 mentioned user groups).

At the moment I am using EdpModuleLayouts for this purpose, which did fine until now. Because now I need to adapt the 3rd layout depending on which usergroup accesses it.

Do you have any idea how to get this done?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have to adapt the layout or just the navigation on it? I mean, the links to the surveys are placed in the menu and you want to hide them to the adminstrators?

Comment: Well there would be several changes so i have to replace the whole layout. The links to the Surveys are not in the Navigation, they are on the main screen where it shows the available survey for the logged in user. But The solution from ins0 works fine, thanks anyways :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can listen you to the zf2 mvc events and change your layout based on your criterias.
this is an example how your application `Module.php` can look like.

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
{
    $application =  $e->getApplication();
    $serviceManager = $application->getServiceManager();
    $eventManager = $application->getEventManager();
    $sharedManager = $eventManager->getSharedManager();

    // DISPATCH EVENT
    $sharedManager->attach('Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController', 'dispatch', function( MvcEvent $e) use ($serviceManager) {

        // get your instance to locate current user group or something else
        $auth = $serviceManager->get('Some/Auth/Service');
        $userGroup = $auth->getUserGroupFromCurrentUser();

        $controller      = $e->getTarget();

        if( $userGroup == 'someGroup' )
        {
            $controller->layout('layout/somelayoutname');
        } else {
            $controller->layout('layout/someotherlayoutname');
        }
    }, 50 );
}
```